# Security for Southbound of lightweightm2m-iotagent?

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-wilma

Can i use the PEP proxy for lightweightm2m-iotagent ?
is there any way to implement security for lightweightm2m-iotagent at southbound side(LWM2M Client to LWM2M Server) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present no security is used, in the future secured coap (coaps:// or COAP over DTLS) will be supported.

Comment: Thank you so much user3016684